# Find the top value from a list of tuples

Tags: python

If I have this list of tuples:

```
[('123c', 0.0), ('123c1', 0.0), ('123c2', 0.10456917162915072), ('123c3', 0.097595441008939465), ('123c4', 0.0), ('12c35', 0.0), ('13836', 0.040490933063262943)]
```

How can I find the top value in the whole list, and return the first element in the tuple it belongs?

For the example above, the result would be: `'123c2'` because `0.10456917162915072` is the top value

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the maximum; the [`max()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#max) does that for you, and you can supply it with a function to determine what value the maximum is determined *by*:

```
from operator import itemgetter

max(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
```

Here, [`operator.itemgetter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter) provides that function; it takes the specified element from any object you pass to it.

Demo:

```
>>> inputlist = [('123c', 0.0), ('123c1', 0.0), ('123c2', 0.10456917162915072), ('123c3', 0.097595441008939465), ('123c4', 0.0), ('12c35', 0.0), ('13836', 0.040490933063262943)]
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> max(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1))[0]
'123c2'
```

Comment: +1 Or `max(inputlist, key=itemgetter(1))[0]` to get the first element, as the OP requested.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
>>> a = [('123c', 0.0), ('123c1', 0.0), ('123c2', 0.10456917162915072), ('123c3', 0.097595441008939465), ('123c4', 0.0), ('12c35', 0.0), ('13836', 0.040490933063262943)]
>>> max(a, key = lambda x: x[1]) # Or max(a, key = itemgetter(1))
('123c2', 0.10456917162915072)
>>> max(a, key = lambda x: x[1])[0]
'123c2'
```

About the `max()` function,

```
max(...)
    max(iterable[, key=func]) -> value
    max(a, b, c, ...[, key=func]) -> value

    With a single iterable argument, return its largest item.
    With two or more arguments, return the largest argument.
```

The second argument to `max(...)` in the above example is the key function which lets the function decide which value to maximise.